# How to scale gevent-socketio server?

Tags: python, real-time, comet, socket.io, gevent

I'm planning to build a realtime service with [gevent-socketio](https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-socketio/src) (released by Jeffrey Gelens). For some purposes, I need to scale my service with many [gevent-socketio](https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-socketio/src) servers. I think it can be used as a reverse proxy (like [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx)) for distributing requests across multiple [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) servers and use another server as a central session datastore, is it right?

I'm trying to modify gevent-socketio source code, but it's rather hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think haproxy is most appropriate for proxying in this manner. You're on the right track with your approach.